# Dataflow exceeds number_of_worker_harness_threads

Tags: multithreading, google-cloud-platform, parallel-processing, apache-beam, dataflow

I deployed Dataflow job with param `--number_of_worker_harness_threads=5` (streaming mode).

Next I send 20x PubSub messages triggering 20x loading big CSV files from GCS and start processing.
In the logs I see that job took 10 messages and process it in parallel on 6-8 threads (I checked several times, sometimes it was 6, sometimes 8).
Nevertheless all the time it was more than 5.

Any idea how it works? It does not seem to be expected behavior.

Comment: Our team experience the same problem. Steaming mode seams to behave different as it works fine in batch mode. From the logs we can see "Currently using 2 threads." even with `--number_of_worker_harness_threads=1` and `experiments=no_use_multiple_sdk_containers`. Manually locking from code doesn't work either. We are trying to get Google support.

Answer (score 1):

Judging from the flag name, you are using Beam Python SDK.
For Python streaming, the total number of threads running DoFns on 1 worker VM in current implementation may be up to the value provided in `--number_of_worker_harness_threads` times the number of SDK processes running on the worker, which by default is the number of vCPU cores. There is a way to limit number of processes to 1 regardless of # of vCPUs. To do so, set `--experiments=no_use_multiple_sdk_containers`.
For example, if you are using `--machine_type=n1-standard-2` and `--number_of_worker_harness_threads=5`, you may have up to 10 DoFn instances in different threads running concurrently on the same machine.

If `--number_of_worker_harness_threads` is not specified, up to 12 threads per process are used. See also: https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/troubleshoot-oom#dofn